# Iphone mpmediaplayer, server connection died

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, media-player

Is there anyway to catch this notification?

```
_serverConnectionDiedNotification. Info -- notification=NSConcreteNotification 0x2e7f70 {name = AVController_ServerConnectionDiedNotification; object = <AVController: 0x2aa2a0>}, AVController = <AVController: 0x2aa2a0>, currentTime = 0.00
```

It occurs when my mediaplayer loses its connection to the server.
I would like to catch this notification and try to reconnect to the server again, to continue playing the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may register for that notification using this method from the [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver selector:(SEL)notificationSelector name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
```

However NSConcreteNotification is a private subclass of the abstract NSNotification class and since Apple doesn't like anyone using private classes I am not sure if that would work.

Comment: What's the notificationName that I'm supposed to use?
I've tried both NSConcreteNotification and AVController_ServerConnectionDiedNotification, but the compiler keeps saying that they are undeclared.
Any imports that I need?

Comment: @Russel the Notification name would be NSConcreteNotification

Comment: Opps, you replied while I was editing.
What import do I need?

Also, any idea how to get the currentTime value out of the notification?

Comment: @Russell Sorry but I do not know what imports you would need, however I think if you add it in XCode it will tell you what it needs. Do you mean the currentTime on the mediaplayer?, I do not think that is possible unfortunately.

Comment: Arghh, XCode didn't say anything. Just keep complaining that it is undeclared.

Also, if you scroll all the way to the right of the log snippet in my question, you can see a currentTime attribute in the notification.
I suppose I could get it using some sort of objectForKey?

Comment: @Russell oh yes I can see the currentTime now, sorry but I really don't know how you could get that. My guess is that XCode didn't say anything because NSConcreteNotification is a private class, you might not be able to do subscribe to this notification.